# Verify numerically that the iterative method is cubically or linear convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Using a function of your choice, verify numerically that the iterative method

$$x_{n+1} =x_n −  \dfrac{f(x_n)}{\sqrt{[f′(x_n)]^2 − \dfrac{f(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}}}$$

is cubically convergent at a simple root but only linearly convergent at a multiple root.

I have to use Matlab/python for this practice question. I have more exposure with python but I can manage with matlab. So to verify it can I use a function like $f(x)=g(x)^{h(x)}$ with $g(x)=(x-r)^n$ for $n$ being some power? Or what should I do next?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write mathematical expressions on this site

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: right i know that but because this is just a practice question for my midterm and i have no idea where to start i am asking for help but thanks for the welcome!

Comment: I presume you should write a program implementing this method and test it on some examples (presumably polynomials) with both simple and multiple roots.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula looks wrong. It is the opposite of the Newton method if the derivative is negative at the root. A root finding method should not change when the function is changed by a constant factor, such a factor would not cancel in the given formula.

A halfway plausible corrected formula that is invariant under rescaling of $f$ and is a refinement of the Newton method would be
$$
x_{n+1}=x_n+h_n=x_n-\frac{sign[f'(x_n)]f(x_n)}{\sqrt{f'(x_n)^2-f(x_n)f''(x_n)}}
$$
With this formula you would get in the Taylor expansion 
\begin{align}
f(x_n+h_n)&=f(x_n)+f'(x_n)h_n+\frac12f''(x_n)h_n^2+O(h_n^3)\\
&=\frac{f\left(f'^2-ff''\right)-|f'|f\sqrt{f'^2-ff''}+\frac12f''f^2}{f'^2-ff''}+O(f(x_n)^3)\\
&=f\frac{(f'^2-\frac12ff'')-|f'|\sqrt{f'^2-ff''}}{f'^2-ff''}+O(f(x_n)^3)\\
&=f\frac{\frac14f^2f''^2}{(f'^2-ff'')\left[(f'^2-\frac12ff'')+|f'|\sqrt{f'^2-ff''}\right]}+O(f(x_n)^3)\\
&=O(f(x_n)^3)
\end{align}
For simple roots the function value is proportional to the distance to the root, so that this computation establishes third order convergence.